# How to increase size of variable and make it bold in portal side as well as platform side in Servicenow

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I have one variable of type label in catalog item, which needs to be bold and increase its size by 4 pts.

I have written onload client script. Size of variable is increasing in portal side but the script is not supporting to platform view. i.e for RITM SCTASK view.
Here is the code

```
function onLoad(){

    setTimeout(function(){ 
        
        if(window != null){
            // platform
            g_form.getControl('project_summary').setAttribute('style', 'font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px');

        }
        else{
            // portal
            var lables = this.document.getElementsByClassName("ng-binding");
            var searchText = "Project Summary";
            var found;

            for (var i = 0; i <lables.length; i++) {
                if (lables[i].textContent.toString() == searchText) {
                    lables[i].style.fontWeight = 'bold';
                    lables[i].style.fontSize = '18px';
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }, 9000);

}
```

Written a client script it is only supporting on portal side, it should support on platform side as well.